# how to invoke server to get data from spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm using google spreadsheet api to visualize data for users and I want to get feedback if data is wrong. I found how to get data from server side to spreadsheet here

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get

but i can't find out how to request sending data from spreadsheet to server. what i thought is write down url in one cell. so if user click url then get data from user's spreadsheet.

Can you suggest me better idea?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it but, you may want to check the use of Google Apps Script Service [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) and see if it will help you. Google Apps Script can interact with APIs from all over the web, see this [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#connect_to_public_apis).

Comment: Thanks for a comment @Teyam. I haven't thought using Google Apps Script because I'm not sure that I can put scripts i wrote into user's browser. Is there a way to do that?